# C# How to use BigInteger with this Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, biginteger

`var totalCost = Persons.Sum(x => BigInteger.Parse(x.cost.First(kv => kv.Key == "volvo").Value))`

**ERROR:**
*Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type '`System.Func< Persons,int >`' 
because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Numerics.BigInteger`' to '`int`'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

I've used it with `OrderByDescending` and it works fine. I can understand the error. I just don't know what to replace `Sum` with to make it work.

How do I properly use `BigInteger` with that statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, no overload of [**`Sum`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) method works with `BigInteger` as of .NET 4.0. You can write an overload that does this yourself, or use the more general purpose [**`Aggregate`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx) operator to do the summation:

```
var totalCost = Persons.Select(x => BigInteger.Parse(x.cost.First(kv => kv.Key == "volvo").Value))
                       .Aggregate(BigInteger.Zero, (sum, next) => sum + next);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't. There's no overload of `Sum` that takes a `BigInteger`, so you'll have to do the summing yourself.

You could always write your own extension method, though:

```
public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static BigInteger Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, BigInteger> selector)
    {
        BigInteger output = 0;

        foreach(TSource item in source)
        {
            output += selector(item);
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

As long as this class is within one of your `using` namespaces, you'll now be able to call `Sum` as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx).

```
//written without an IDE...
var bigIntegerSum = Persons.Aggregate( (sum, next) => sum + next);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that your variable is called "totalCost", I'm going to guess that you're dealing with money, in which case `decimal` is a better type than `BigInteger`. And since `decimal` has an overload for `Sum`, it will work if you use:

```
var totalCost = Persons.Sum(x =>
                     Decimal.Parse(x.cost.First(kv => kv.Key == "volvo").Value))
```